# 60hz on LG Ultrafine 4K with Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: display, high-sierra, 4k

I'm struggling to get 4096 x 2304 at 60hz using the hardware mentioned.

It works intermittently. If I unplug and replug the monitor cable, it sometimes comes back in 60hz. But then it reverts to 30hz after waking from sleep.

I've installed SwitchResX and the 60hz resolutions are just missing sometimes - see https://www.evernote.com/l/AFUEaitsECJFb59g2P7zgyefBMlpgAOLw9U

I could be imagining it, but I think it was running at 60hz reliably before my recent High Sierra upgrade.

Apple say 60hz is supported on my hardware here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207447

I suspect my cable is bad. I'm using the one that came with the monitor. I've ordered another, so I'll see if that fixes it. ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01CEFESRO/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CEFESRO))

I notice that the shorter cables have higher bandwidth ratings, so hopefully this 3 foot cable is better than the 8 foot cable that ships with the monitor.

Has anyone else experiences this problem? Any advice?

Comment: I'm hopeful that having done a NVRAM and SMC reset has solved the problem. Time will tell. See https://discussions.apple.com/message/32608748

Comment: I tried these 2 cables, but they made no difference:

- Belkin USB-IF Certified USB-C to USB-C Thunderbolt 3 Cable, Compatible with Thunderbolt 3 and USB 3.1 (3 Feet) 

- Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Cable (USB-C to USB-C), 100 Watts (1.6 Feet / 0.5 Meters) - F2CD084bt0.5MBK

Comment: Problem is back, so NVRAM and SMC reset doesn't solve the problem. I now have to figure out if the problem is with my Mac or with the UltraFine display...

Comment: Actually I now strongly suspect High Sierra is the problem. See     https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8087652?start=0&tstart=0 . I'm gonna wait for a High Sierra update and hope that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm switching between Gigabit Lan, superb usb mouse and 4k@30hz - and 4k@60hz in combination with only slow WLAN and terrible bluetooth mouse on my 2016 Macbook.

I experienced the same issues with a longer monitor cable in the 60hz Setup at a customer and his monitor. The problem was solved when I used my better and shorter cable. Display was a Samsung 4k display though.

Comment: Shucks, I tried with these 2 cables and it didn't solve the problem

- Belkin USB-IF Certified USB-C to USB-C Thunderbolt 3 Cable, Compatible with Thunderbolt 3 and USB 3.1 (3 Feet) 

- Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Cable (USB-C to USB-C), 100 Watts (1.6 Feet / 0.5 Meters) - F2CD084bt0.5MBK